# Azure Failover Cluster Backup

Tags: azure, azure-sql, storage-spaces-direct

We have configured a failover cluster instance in Azure (iaas), and we are running SQL 2016, and we have a backup directory presented as a csv (which is a mountpoint on the c: drive, under c:\clusterstorage) this is using storage spaces direct s2D.

When we do a file recovery in Azure it restores the drive but the drives are empty, we assume as these are mount points the actual data resides on the actual storage layer, my question is how do we do file level recovery in azure using storage spaces direct S2D?

This has us stumped. Hopefully get some clarity on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you stick with FCI and flaky S2D, instead of going with SQL Server AGs or BAGs?

Comment: @RiGiD5 Hi, We did consider AGs but cost is a factor so we went for FCI, which is half the cost and we are going to Azure therefore need to have TDE enabled which is limited to SQL ent edt .. which is costly, but now not seeing a solution to backup the databases.

Comment: Storage Spaces Direct being an extremely immature tech itself is a very poorly matched with SQL Server.